# Prestashop 1.7 Create new classes for modules and overrided controllers

Tags: class, module, controller, overriding, prestashop

I started with prestashop and I have an organizational problem in my code. I created several modules and new tables. I also overrided controllers in the myprestashop/override/ folder in which I want to use my tables, so I have to create new classes. But I don't know where to create classes in prestashop for as much access in my modules as in my overrided controllers.

For now I'm calling my classes create in my modules, in my overridded controllers. Although I know it's not the right solution.

```
require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'my_module/classes/MyNewClass.php'
```

Would someone have the answer?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Well your way is acceptable solution as PrestaShop doesn't have any autoloading capabilities for custom classes.

However what I like to do is use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) in modules and use its [autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) capabilities for my classes and any libraries that the module might need.

**Update**

An example of composer usage in `myexample` module:

Module structure

```
modules/
  myexample/
     classes/
       mynamespace/             
     myexample.php
     composer.json
```

`myexample.php`

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

class MyExample extends Module
{
    // module code
}
```

`composer.json`

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "mynamespace\\": "classes/mynamespace"
    }
  }
}
```

Run `composer install` from module folder.

Now you can put classes under `mynamespace` folder (with proper namespace definition of course) and they get autoloaded anywhere your module is used (module controllers, models, hooks etc).

Comment: Could you elaborate that a bit more?

Comment: @toesslab Added explanation

Comment: thanj you for that

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that below scheme works too in version 1.7.6, but I would ask experienced developers to point if this is correct approach.

I put my custom class file into `/override/classes` folder:

```
namespace CustomNamespace;

class CustomClass {
...
}
```

then in other places I just use the class:

```
use \CustomNamespace\CustomClass;
```

and my CustomClass works as expected